# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [164, 41]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, random-forest

am trying to make a predictive model with random forest which predict the CarName as predictor and features are gas,rear,two.

CarName is categorical var and the rest is numeric.
while trying to run the below code am getting this error, could anyone please help me out with it, thanks in advance, here's my code.

```
snipets...

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X=df6[['gas','rear','two']] #these are all in int form
y=df6[['CarName']].values.reshape(-1,1) # this is in object form
X_train,X_test,y_test,y_train=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)


from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

the error am getting.

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-4c45187c84b2> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
      2 clf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
----> 3 clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    302                 "sparse multilabel-indicator for y is not supported."
    303             )
--> 304         X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, multi_output=True,
    305                                    accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
    306         if sample_weight is not None:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    431                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
    432             else:
--> 433                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    434             out = X, y
    435 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
    829         y = y.astype(np.float64)
    830 
--> 831     check_consistent_length(X, y)
    832 
    833     return X, y

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    260     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    261     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 262         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
    263                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    264 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [164, 41]
```

the shape of my df.

```
X_train.shape,y_train.shape
    Out[53]:
    ((164, 3), (41, 1)) #I guess this is the code which giving me error but am unable to solve it
```

Comment: As the error says, you need to make sure that you have a one-one correspondence between your data and labels. You can't have 41 labels for 164 datapoints.

Comment: @Ananda how can I do it, could you please show me the exaple

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20199/train-test-split-error-found-input-variables-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is cos of this:

```
X_train,X_test,y_test,y_train=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
```

The mapping of values happens in this order based on train_test_split's return:

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test
```

ie. y_train followed by y_test, hence the shape mismatch. Just change this and it'll work fine.